# Get base URL of webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, webapi

(typing from mobile)
I got a webapi with an action based http controller.
So there are no web pages just API.
vsstudio generates localhost:port URLs when deployed localhost.
I wonder how to get the base URL even if it's deployed elsewhere.
There must be some environment var I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the base URL from the HTTPContext. I wrote some sample code for you, hope it helps!

```
[Route("api")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getBaseUrl")]
    public string GetBaseUrl()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Request;

        var baseUrl = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}:{request.PathBase.ToUriComponent()}";

        return baseUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll mark as answer, though i settled eventually width  
var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)